# vscode の markdown でテーブルをフォーマットしたい

Tags: vscode, markdown

github でサポートされている markdown のテーブル表記は、以下のフォーマットです。

```
| header1 | hearder2 |
| ------- | --- |
| field1 | field2 |
| field3     | field 4 |
```

これだと生テキスト上は見にくいので、以下のような形へ整形してほしいと考えました。

```
| header1 | hearder2 |
| ------- | -------- |
| field1  | field2   |
| field3  | field 4  |
```

#### 質問

- これを実現する vscode のプラグインやコマンドなどはありますか？

Answer (score 1):

私が使っているプラグインはこれです。

[Shuzo Iwasaki / Table Formatter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=shuworks.vscode-table-formatter)

Comment: マーケットプレイスで
`@sort:installs table`
などと調べると出てくると思います。